# Cannot move camera in viewport, nor move reference jpeg images

Tags: transforms

I'm struggling with an issue, my camera and reference images won't budge when I try and move them, the arrows won't select/move the items, it just creates a dashed line box selection. When I change the values numerically the items move, but this is largely not an option I can teach with. Other computers on our network don't give me the same issue, only a specific desktop in my classroom. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, trying the new beta build too, but the problem persists. I have also tried deleting all Blender related files on the c drive where it is installed. Any advice greatly appreciated.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add an image of Blender's full window to your question. Might give us a clue as to what's going on! In Blender, Window > Save Screenshot then https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Hi John

It's giving me this error when I try and insert it...

'Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server'

Comment: That's unfortunate. There's another questioner reporting the same upload error so it looks like a system problem. Does this happen with a completely new Blend file or one saved from one of your other computers? You could also upload a Blend file that is showing the problem: https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: Thanks for replying John, I've uploaded the file, it happens on both old and new.

Comment: Well it's no consolation to you, but I can move both camera and reference image by dragging with the mouse or gizmo without problem here. Have you tried that file on other computers without loading the UI? - Press 'N' in the file selector when loading into Blender and uncheck 'Load UI'.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue with the empty image object and one of the camera. However, the scene's active camera is hidden: hidden objects can't be selected and manipulated in the viewport. If that's the one you were having problems with, try to un-hide it first by checking ON its eye icon in the outliner.

Comment: Thanks all, I'll try your advice when I get back on the machine after half-term, much appreciated.